# I am creating a social networking site like facebook. I want to develop a chat system. I am having trouble with database management

Tags: mysql, mongodb

There are so many posts on this topic but that didn't helped me...

I want to develop a 2 user chat system as I mentioned in title. What I have in my mind is as follow...

**Whats in my mind :**

1:Create database named as chat...

That database will have different tables. And their names will be the Id of the users like if I have two users who have ID "12" and "33" then table name will be like this "12 33" or something like this...And that table will contain the chat of these 2 users...

**How will I fetch that ?**

Well I never did this before but the idea in my mind is I will get the tables name from chat database. And then convert table name into array...It will get something like this  [ 12 , 13 ]....Then I will check if current users (who have logged into my system) id matches with the values in the array, then it I will get all the columns in that table and show them to the users..

**Which database I will use?**

I am confused which database is best for me!

**If you have some better idea then please share that with me**

Comment: You shouldn't have a table which only stores conversations between two users. That won't scale at all.

Comment: It could be done and scaled using either of Databases, np there. Fro simplicity sake just get the ID of the user logged in and get the chats from the DB and display to the user

Answer (score 0):

When you implementing this you cant use two table to save the message content or whatever data you have save.

I have a solution like below it can manage more than two users to handle the chat system.

**Create Two table as**

1. user
2. message

Check [Simple ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQPJG.jpg)

in **user** table add columns user_id, user_name, state and the message**message** table add columns msg_id, msg_date, msg_time, msg_content, sender_id, receiver_id.

and join the table as one to many, and get the message data in message table filter by the date and time, also you can use the user table state column for update user state as user is online or offline.

hope you can get the idea. if you have any issue put a comment below.

Comment: Bro thanks for your idea BUT issue here is that let suppose I have too much users chatting with each other and as you suggested, message table will get millions and billions of columns and It will be difficult to to iterate over them and grab the chat of specific user.

Comment: yes, you can fetch the data using date and limit for some range. That's my idea for this also you can use user local storage as your message list for reduce the server calls, when scroll or search the old messages fetch the data from the server db, and thanks for your response.